# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" Position: 1 when use \copy

Tags: database, postgresql

I try to copy csv to database table postgres using

```
\copy sik FROM '/Users/bhaskoromuthohar/dev/generate_file_ruby/12345620201214SIK01.csv' DELIMITER '|' csv;
```

But it raised

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
  Position: 1
```

I googled the error but couldn't find the answer to my problem. Any bits of help is appreciated, thankyou

Comment: Why the ``\``??

Comment: @juergend CMIIW, because the database is in the cloud and I use SQL client to access it then the location of the CSV is in my localhost machine so I need ```\```

Comment: You are apparently not using `psql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Backslash commands” are only recognized by the command line client `psql`, so you will have to use that client.